# Standard ML printing control characters

Tags: printing, casting, sml, smlnj, control-characters

So I've stumbled on what seems to be a weird little problem. I want to print control characters, which should print that weird little box suggesting that I'm trying to print a non-printable character.

When I try:

```
print "\^C";
```

it works fine. However when I do:

```
print (Char.toString(#"\^C"));
```

it literally prints "\^C". This doesn't make any sense to me, shouldn't they be printing the same thing? Char.toString doesn't convert the character to a string with one character in it, it converts it to a string with 3 characters in it, '\', '^', and 'C'.

Would somebody explain this behavior to me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`Char.toString`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/char.html#SIG%3aCHAR.toString%3aVAL) returns a printable representation of the character.

If you wish to do a direct conversion from `char` to `string`, you need to use the [`str`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.str%3aVAL) function.